# Run module function over FeatureCollection and write results into table in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

This is a follow up question on ([Extract and plot from an Array in GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357754/extract-and-plot-from-an-array-in-gee)) but can also be treated as a standalone question.

I want to run a LandTrendr analysis for a given number of points (coordinates) and write the results into a table such as

```
feature.id | year | original | fitted
00_00      | 2001 | 1001.00  | 1002.10
00_01      | 2002 | 1021.00  | 1050.20
...
01_00      | 2001 | 2001.00  | 2002.10
01_01      | 2002 | 3001.00  | 3002.10
...
```

My function over the FeatureCollection is not working and I can't get it right.

```
// Points
var p1 = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.64550158728298,38.44643840127136]);
var p2 = ee.Geometry.Point([-123.06960473413164,38.54089331487732]);
var p3 = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.85149523962673,38.33988067525676]);
var fg_points = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([ee.Feature(p1),ee.Feature(p2),ee.Feature(p3)]));

Map.setCenter(-122.64550158728298,38.44643840127136, 11);
Map.addLayer(feat);

// load LandTrendr module
var ltgee = require('users/emaprlab/public:Modules/LandTrendr.js');

// define parameters
var startYear = 1985;
var endYear = 2018;
var startDay = '06-20';
var endDay = '09-20';
var index = 'NBR';
var ftvList = ["NBR"];
var maskThese = ['cloud', 'shadow', 'snow'];

//// function to map over the FeatureCollection
var mapfunc = function(feat) {

  var geom = feat.geometry()

  var collection = ltgee.buildSRcollection(startYear, endYear, startDay, endDay, geom, maskThese)
  var timeSeries = ltgee.buildLTcollection(collection, index, ftvList)

  var lt = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendr({ 
    timeSeries:             timeSeries,
    maxSegments:            6,
    spikeThreshold:         0.9,
    vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
    preventOneYearRecovery: true,
    recoveryThreshold:      0.25,
    pvalThreshold:          0.05,
    bestModelProportion:    0.75,
    minObservationsNeeded:  6
  });

  var fittedImage = ltgee.getFittedData(lt, startYear, endYear, index);

  var fittedCollection = ee.ImageCollection(fittedImage.bandNames()
  .map(function (yearString) {
    yearString = ee.String(yearString);
    return fittedImage.select(yearString)
      .set('system:time_start', ee.Date.parse('yyyy', yearString).millis())
      .rename('Fitted');
  })
  ); 

  // get feature id
  var id = ee.String(feat.id());

  // make an empty list to store the features
  var newfc = ee.List([])
  //// function to iterate over fittedCollection
  var addVals = function(img, fc) {
    // the initial value is the empty list
    fc = ee.List(fc)
    // get the date as string
    var date = img.date().format()
    //// extract the value of 'Fitted'
    var value = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 30).get('Fitted')
    // If the value is null then store it as 'No data'
    var val = ee.String(ee.Algorithms.If(value, ee.String(value), ee.String('No data')))
    // make the name of the feature (feat_id-date)
    var featname = ee.String("feat_").cat(id).cat(ee.String("-")).cat(date)

    // make the Feature
    var newfeat = ee.Feature(geom, {name:featname,
                                    value:val})
    // add the value to the list
     return fc.add(newfeat)
  }
  var newfeat = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(yearly.iterate(addVals, newfc)))
  return newfeat;
};

var newft = fg_points.map(mapfunc).flatten();

Export.table.toDrive(newft,
"export_Points");
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1acf553943e0bba49bca66878e8644c8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There came up several errors when I tried run the code. [This](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a15d52907a02b82305ee1cdeebbe3652) should work as you wanted I guess.

1. In line 8 you try to add `feat` to the map, which is not yet defined.
2. Your if statement was malformatted. If a dictionary does not have a key, an error will be dropped if you try to get that value. Use:

```
      var val = ee.String(ee.Algorithms.If(value.contains('Fitted'),                                          
        ee.String(value.get('Fitted')),ee.String('No data')))
```

3. something in your function `addvals()` was not working. I didn't find what exactly. You should better use mapping instead of an iterate function. See this example:

```
    // get feature id
    var id = ee.String(feat.id());
    var newfeat = fittedCollection.map(function(image){
    var value = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 30);
    // If the value is null then store it as 'No data'
    var val = ee.String(ee.Algorithms.If(value.contains('Fitted'), ee.String(value.get('Fitted')), ee.String('No data')))
    var featname = ee.String("feat_").cat(id).cat(ee.String("")).cat(image.date().format()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description and the link! Works perfectly.